Optimize NAMD2 on multiple nodes using OpenMPI
I'm currently running NAMD2 on a server with EPYC CPUs using the specifications below:
    ...
    #SBATCH --nodes=1
    #SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=128
    #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
    #SBATCH --mem=249208M
    ...
    time -p mpirun \
         -np 4      \
        --map-by ppr:4:node     \
          namd2 +setcpuaffinity  \
                +ppn 31           \
                +commap 0,32,64,96 \
                +pemap 1-31,33-63,65-95,97-127 \
          namd_eq01_1node.conf \
       &> namd_eq01_1node.log


I'm assigning cores for communication and workers within NAMD2 and it scales up almost linearly at the core level (using one node). The problem is when I move to 2 nodes and run the job with:
    time -p mpirun \
         -np 8      \
        --map-by ppr:4:node \
          namd2 +setcpuaffinity \
                +ppn 31          \
                +commap 0,32,64,96\
                +pemap 1-31,33-63,65-95,97-127 \
          namd_eq01_1node.conf \
       &> namd_eq01_1node.log

I'll get a 25 percent penalty hit in my scaling. I've tried to mess with openmpi to reserve a core for communication between the nodes:
    time -p mpirun \
         -np 8      \
        --map-by ppr:4:node \
        --bind-to core       \
        --cpu-list 0-126:31   \
        --report-bindings      \
        --display-devel-map     \
          namd2 +setcpuaffinity  \
                +ppn 31           \
                +commap 0,32,64,96 \
                +pemap 1-31,33-63,65-95,97-126 \
          namd_eq01_2node.conf \
       &> namd_eq01_2node.log

but I had no luck with it, as I always get a policy error.
slurm/expanse/23.02.7
cpu/0.15.4
gcc/10.2.0
openmpi/4.0.4

